# Where does Delphi store global options and can they be overridden in source code?

Tags: delphi

I know I can change project options in the following:

[image: Project Options]

So, where are these stored? And Can these settings be overrided in each source file? for example,

```
{$IOCHECKS ON}
```

Comment: These settings are stored in the project .dproj file, or a referenced option set file. They can be overridden in specific source files.

Comment: Also, it's worth being very clear that these are not global options, these are project options

Comment: In an IDE source window, pressing Ctrl-O, O will insert the current compiler options, fwiw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where are these stored?

The [compiler directives](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Seattle/en/Delphi_Compiler_Directives_(List)_Index) are stored in the `.dproj` file.

There are [Option Sets](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Option_Sets_Overview) files that can be used for saving/setting user specified options.

> Can these settings be overrided in each source file?

Some directives are global and some local. The local ones can be overridden in the unit files, while the global ones in the project main source file.

These settings are often stored in [include files](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Include_file_(Delphi)) (*.inc) and referenced in the units files.

Comment: You might add using *.inc files for overriding.

Comment: @UliGerhardt, yes that is a common use case.

Comment: Might be worth to mention what people use single include file in many source files because compiler forgets directives at the end of each source file and reverts to project's ones.

Comment: One more thing to add ,is that DPROJ file uses 2D matrix of parameters nesting, looks like something like CSS for settings. Sadly IDE is buggy with that at times, and screws things so that you have to open XML sources to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Delphi (specifically D5 and D7, I know), these environment values (not Project specific) are stored in the registry.

For example, with D5 -
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Delphi\5.0\

The Library search path -
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Delphi\5.0\Library

(In some installations, I suspect it might be under [HKey_Local_Machine] instead.)

As far as overriding them in source code, I'm not familiar with that aspect but I would suspect that if it's even possible, it would have to be done with compiler directives. Just a guess in case it's helpful as a starting point.